# react component disappears on heroku after a second

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mern

my website is https://swiftdeskph.herokuapp.com/
when you access my site, it will show the component for a second then its empty

My observations/question:

1. accessing any route not specified shows my Error404 component just fine.
2. even if there is an error on my api call, it should return and display the error in component. Which is whats happening on my dev server.
3. no error on heroku logs
4. If i rewrite my server.js and just put

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {

    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
```

The whole app is working just fine BUT will only work if you start accessing from "/" route.

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import "./sass/App.scss";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// COMPONENTS---------------------------------------
import Navbar from "./components/NavbarComponent";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import { Orders } from "./components/Orders/Orders";
import UserInventory from "./components/UserInventory/UserInventory";
import Error404 from "./components/Error404";

//Import fetch actions
import { fetchProducts } from "./redux/userInventory/inventoryActions";
import { fetchOrder } from "./redux/order/orderActions";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchOrder());
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="appContainer">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/orders" component={Orders} />
            <Route path="/inventory" component={UserInventory} />
            <Route path="*" component={Error404} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;
const { MONGO_URI } = require("./config/keys");
const connection = mongoose.connection;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
});

connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully.");
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  const path = require("path");
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

//ADDING OF ROUTES
const products = require("./routes/products");
const userInventory = require("./routes/userInventory");
const transactions = require(".//routes/transactions");
app.use("/api/products", products);
app.use("/api/user/inventory", userInventory);
app.use("/api/transactions", transactions);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you look at your console, you get this

[image]

Looks like you are calling map on orders, where orders is not an array. Its possibly null/undefined/object/value type.

look at DashboardOrders.jsx

Comment: I'll add a condition to map only when it has value and see how it works. This is weird though since there is a default value for my state which is empty array. Also again, the whole think works if i use  app.get("/", (req, res) =>  in server.js

Comment: still the same issue. 

https://imgur.com/a/T1h4VI9

Comment: what is the first api call made? `https://swiftdeskph.herokuapp.com/api/transactions` ?

Comment: i deleted all content in inventory, and it is showing. i think it goes to show that the problem is in api calls.

in app.js there is 2 api calls to fetch orders & inventory.

Comment: my /inventory only uses the inventory state. i commented out anything about orders and see if it will work when there is only 1 api request

Comment: i console log my array in this route
https://swiftdeskph.herokuapp.com/inventory
it appears the return of my request is an html. i'll try to fix this later

Comment: its becoz any route will return my index.html as stated in server. idk how to fix it yet

Comment: yup. You can inspect the network tab with devtools, and the routes return html. can you post contents of products from the server?

Comment: using postman yes. still trying to figure the fix for this

Comment: I am starting to get it now. My question should be: Can i host a fullstack mern app with rest API on heroku in 1 server? I know my issue can easily be fixed if i move my react app to a new heroku project and connect the api requests to my backend heroku server. I just want to know if there is an alternative before i do that

Answer (score 1):

Issue fix. Since issue is conflict with routes, i just manually coded the routes.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  const path = require("path");
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
  app.get("/orders", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
  app.get("/inventory", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```